# numpy where with fill string formatting

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Given a df like below

```
name    id1 id2 id3 id4 fid
foo 1   3   4   5   t
bar 11  13  14  15  a
foo 21  23  24  25  f
bar 31  33  34  35  v
foo 41  43  44  45  f
```

using np.where i am trying to create 3 more columns which needs string formatting before fill

```
df['idA'] = np.where(df.name == 'foo',
'{}:{}-{}({})'.format(df.id1,df.id2,df.id3+1,df.fid),
'{}:{}-{}({})'.format(df.id1,df.id2,df.id4+1,df.fid))

df['idB'] = np.where(df.name == "foo",
'{}:{}-{}({})'.format(df.id1,df.id4,df.id3+1,df.fid),
'{}:{}-{}({})'.format(df.id1,df.id3,df.id2+1,df.fid))

df['idC'] = np.where(df.name == 'foo',
'{}:{}-{}({})'.format(df.id1,df.id2,df.id3+1,df.fid),
'{}:{}-{}({})'.format(df.id1,df.id3,df.id2+1,df.fid))
print(df)
```

However using above code you can see

```
  name  id1  ...                                                idB                                                idC
0  foo    1  ...  0     1\n1    11\n2    21\n3    31\n4    41\nN...  0     1\n1    11\n2    21\n3    31\n4    41\nN...
1  bar   11  ...  0     1\n1    11\n2    21\n3    31\n4    41\nN...  0     1\n1    11\n2    21\n3    31\n4    41\nN...
2  foo   21  ...  0     1\n1    11\n2    21\n3    31\n4    41\nN...  0     1\n1    11\n2    21\n3    31\n4    41\nN...
3  bar   31  ...  0     1\n1    11\n2    21\n3    31\n4    41\nN...  0     1\n1    11\n2    21\n3    31\n4    41\nN...
4  foo   41  ...  0     1\n1    11\n2    21\n3    31\n4    41\nN...  0     1\n1    11\n2    21\n3    31\n4    41\nN...

[5 rows x 9 columns]
```

I could figure out that using format to create a string is causing this issue, don't see it while using simple strings

```
df['idA'] = np.where(df.name == "foo","too","tar")
df['idB'] = np.where(df.name == "foo","tar1","too1")
df['idC'] = np.where(df.name == "foo","zoo1","zoo2")

print(df)

name  id1  id2  id3  id4 fid  idA   idB   idC
0  foo    1    3    4    5   t  too  tar1  zoo1
1  bar   11   13   14   15   a  tar  too1  zoo2
2  foo   21   23   24   25   f  too  tar1  zoo1
3  bar   31   33   34   35   v  tar  too1  zoo2
4  foo   41   43   44   45   f  too  tar1  zoo1
```

is there an elegant way of passing strings to np.where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `df.apply` to generate the strings row by row:

```py
foo_mask = df.name == 'foo'
df.loc[ foo_mask, 'idA'] = df.loc[ foo_mask].apply(lambda row: f'{row.id1}:{row.id2}-{row.id3+1}({row.fid})', axis=1)
df.loc[~foo_mask, 'idA'] = df.loc[~foo_mask].apply(lambda row: f'{row.id1}:{row.id2}-{row.id4+1}({row.fid})', axis=1)
print(df)
```

gives

```
  name  id1  id2  id3  id4 fid          idA
0  foo    1    3    4    5   t     1:3-5(t)
1  bar   11   13   14   15   a  11:13-16(a)
2  foo   21   23   24   25   f  21:23-25(f)
3  bar   31   33   34   35   v  31:33-36(v)
4  foo   41   43   44   45   f  41:43-45(f)
```

Depending of the size of the DataFrame, this might be slower than a vectorized solution. However, the slightly nicer string formatting could be worth it for readability.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `{}.format` you are coercing the arrays to strings. instead, use pandas built-in [string operations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html).

Instead of `'{}:{}-{}({})'.format(df.id1,df.id2,df.id3+1,df.fid)`, use:

```py
(
    df.id1.astype('str')
    + ':' + df.id2.astype(str)
    + '-' + (df.id3 + 1).astype(str)
    + '(' + df.fid.astype(str) + ')
)
```